# How to open specific folder by Opendialog in VB?

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I' m making program which export data from excel saved on disk to my textboxes in Form Application.

I have in code constant localization of excel.

```
 Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim ReteilerWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\TR\2.xlsx")

    With OpenFileDialog1
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        .ShowDialog()
    End With
```

Now i want to add button with opendialog to choose the Excel from different localization.

Comment: change InitialDirectory to your new location f.e C:\Users\TR\ or SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments. Then the openfiledialog will start in that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the file you want manually by using the OpenFileDialog

```
Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog With {
            .CheckFileExists = True
        }

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
            Dim ReteilerWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

        End If
```